# SQL query that will return entries sharing certain column value from the same table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have more or less the following table:

| list_id | key |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | b |
| 1 | c |
| 2 | d |
| 2 | e |
| 3 | f |
| 3 | g |
| ... | ... |

Given a certain key or set of keys, what sql query will return all the keys that share a given `list_id`. For example, given key *a*, I want to return *a, b, c*. Given *a,d*, I should get back *a,b,c,d,e*.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to select the list_ids you want in a subquery / cte and from there filter the rest, e.g.

```
WITH j (id) AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT list_id FROM t
  WHERE key IN ('a','d')
)
SELECT key FROM t
JOIN j ON j.id = t.list_id;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/zQ-Y1jA7)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `exists`:

```
select key
from mytable t
where exists (
    select 1 from mytable t1 where t1.key in ('a', 'd')  and t1.list_id = t.list_id
)
```

If two keys might match on more than one list_id, then you would probably need `select distinct key` to avoid duplicates in the resultset (although that's not the case for your example data).

This query would take likely advantage of an index on `mytable(key, list_id)` (or `mytable(list_id, key)` depending on the cardinality of the two columns).